# passar variaveis do AJAX para PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando passar valores através de duas variáveis no AJAX para um arquivo PHP, porem não esta dando certo. se eu colocar **data: { idUsuario: "5", idEscolha: "1", }** da certo. O que esta errado?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#botao").click(function(){

        var url = "InserirEscolha.php";

$.ajax({
    var idUsuario = "5";
    var idEscolha = "1";
  type: 'post',
  url: 'UpdateVisto.php',
  data: { idUsuario: idUsuario, idEscolha: idEscolha, }
});

        $.post(url, function(result) {

        });

    });

});
```

---

```
<?php
$idUsuario = $_POST['idUsuario'];
$idEscolha = $_POST['idEscolha'];

include "config_sistema.php";

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuario_escolha
            (id_usuario, id_escolha)
            VALUES('{idUsuario}','{$idEscolha}')");

if ($query){
    header("Location: perfil.php?ID=$idUsuario");
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual código não funciona o `$.ajax` ou o `$.post`? o primeiro exemplo está certo, você não mostrou em qual exemplo falha.

Comment: $.ajax. 
Quando uso as variáveis idUsuario e idEscolha, ele não recebe os valores. Se eu informar os valores diretamente sem as variáveis da certo

Comment: Tenta passar assim `data: {'idUsuario': idUsuario, 'idEscolha': idEscolha, }`

Comment: Agora deu certo,
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa definir os parâmetros enviados, nesse caso adicione aspas nomes para que fique identificaveis no php.

```
data: { 'idUsuario': idUsuario, 'idEscolha': idEscolha, }
```

Se for deixado da forma abaixo o php receberá o post com parâmetros nomeados  5 e 1 no lugar de `idUsuario` e `idEscolha`.

```
data: { idUsuario: idUsuario, idEscolha: idEscolha, }
```